# Implement Unit test case for soap TraceExtension

Tags: unit-testing, soap, nunit, trace

One of the applications in which I am working right now has already implemented [TraceExtension](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34381/Efficient-Tracing-Using-SOAP-Extensions-in-NET?msg=5678212#xx5678212xx).

A new requirement is to create unit tests using NUnit on the same TraceExtension class and check scenarios.

As I am new for a unit test I don't know where to start and how to do it.

Any suggestions will be helpful for me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Include the relevant details in the post. Not much help can be provided without the relevant  details included in the question itself.

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for viewing my post but I only have these details with me. As I can not share my code as it is a violation of company's policy where I am working right now.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you don't have NUnit added as a dependency for your project, follow [these steps to add it](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Installation). If your team have already written NUnit tests before, this step is probably redundant.

Next, create your test class. If you do have no prior tests, you may need to setup the project structure for your tests. It's common practice to create a separate Tests project where all tests live. Have a read of [this example to see what I mean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/testing-with-cli) (the relevant part of that article starts at the heading 'Testing the sample')

When it comes to writing the test code, you should test the public methods of the extension class (the methods that are intended for calling classes to use). Think about scenarios you'd like to test, and write independent test methods for each scenario.

You don't say whether you're using .NET Core or non-Core .NET. Either way, there's plenty of Microsoft tutorials showing what test code looks like [like this example for NUnit and .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-nunit). The NUnit documentation also has [detailed information on it's syntax and how to do everything from write custom test setup code to define test assertions] (https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/NUnit-Documentation) (see the right-hand side, all links under the 'Writing Tests' heading)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is general guidance for all the unit test and I need guidance for the file which I have used in my application which I also shared in my question (TraceExtension). I am not able to understand the structure of the file but I want to understand and create the test case for that and need the guidance for the same.